# How do I return a different column in a 2d array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code here:

```
function getName() {
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetIdHere/edit#gid=0')
    .getSheetByName("Paste Data")
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i][8] = id) {
      return data[i][5];
    } else {
      return "Student Not Found";
    }
  }
}
```

It should be looking at the user input in the spreadsheet cell and matching it to a row in another spreadsheet. I'm trying to make it match row [i] and return me column [5] when matched to column [8]. At the moment, it seems to return the first row and the id it found, but they are not in the same row.

Please help.

Comment: try using data[i][8] == id

Comment: Did you tried this: `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){` ?

Comment: I had tried all three = versions, no better results. I tried `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){`, with no different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to compare the value in `data[i][8]` to the `id` instead of actually comparing you were assigning `id` value to `data[i][8]`. 
Corrected version as follows:

```
function getName() {
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetIdHere/edit#gid=0')
                           .getSheetByName("Paste Data")
                           .getDataRange()
                           .getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][8] == id) {
      return data[i][5];
    }
  }
  return "Student Not Found";
}
```